Jenkins does not recognize command sf?
I've been having a lot of trouble trying to get a Jenkinsfile to work. I've been trying to run this script. Its purpose is to authorize a target salesforce org (=environment) and then to deploy code from a specific branch on a github repository to this Salesforce org:
#!groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
node {
    
    def BUILD_NUMBER=env.BUILD_NUMBER
    def RUN_ARTIFACT_DIR="tests/${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    def SFDC_USERNAME
    
    def HUB_ORG=env.HUB_ORG_PROD
    def SFDC_HOST = env.SFDC_HOST_PROD
    def JWT_KEY_CRED_ID = env.JWT_CRED_ID_PROD
    def CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY=env.CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY_PROD
    
    println 'KEY IS' 
    println JWT_KEY_CRED_ID
    println HUB_ORG
    println SFDC_HOST
    println CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY
    def toolbelt = tool 'toolbelt'

    stage('checkout source') {
        // when running in multi-branch job, one must issue this command
            checkout scm
    }
    
    withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
    
        withCredentials([file(credentialsId: JWT_KEY_CRED_ID, variable: 'jwt_key_file')]) {
            stage('Deploye Code') {
                env.PATH = env.PATH + ";c:\\Windows\\System32"
                if (isUnix()) {
                    rc = sh returnStatus: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf org login jwt --username ${HUB_ORG} --jwt-key-file ${jwt_key_file} --client-id ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} --instance-url ${SFDC_HOST} --set-default-dev-hub"
                }else{
                bat "${toolbelt}/sf update"
                //bat "${toolbelt}/sf org logout --target-org ${HUB_ORG} --no-prompt" 
                     rc = bat returnStatus: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf org login jwt --username ${HUB_ORG} --jwt-key-file ${jwt_key_file} --client-id ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} --instance-url ${SFDC_HOST} --set-default-dev-hub"
                }
            
                if (rc != 0) { 
                println 'inside rc 0'
                error 'hub org authorization failed' 
            }
            else{
                println 'rc not 0'
            }

                println rc
                
                // need to pull out assigned username
                if (isUnix()) {
                    //rmsg = sh returnStdout: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf project deploy start --metadata-dir manifest/. --target-org ${HUB_ORG}"
                    rmsg = sh returnStdout: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf project deploy start --manifest manifest/package.xml --target-org ${HUB_ORG}"
                }else{
                    rmsg = bat returnStdout: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf project deploy start --manifest manifest/package.xml --target-org ${HUB_ORG}"
                   //rmsg = bat returnStdout: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sf project deploy start --metadata-dir manifest/. --target-org ${HUB_ORG}"
                }
                  
                printf rmsg
                println('Hello from a Job DSL script!')
                println(rmsg)
            }
        }
    }

}

But I keep getting this error when trying to build:
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploye Code)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] bat

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\vOpsWithSalesforceDxUdemyCourse_>/sf update 
'/sf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


The logfile suggests that it has a problem with the following line of code bat "${toolbelt}/sf update"
For info:
The Jenkins project is of type "multibranch pipeline".
I'm running this on a Windows machine.
I imagine there is a problem for Jenkins to reach my windows environment variables, where I specified for the "Path" environment variable a number of paths, among which the path to the sf.cmd file. Since it can't reach it, it issues the above-mentioned error message.
Note:
I had a similar error before with the code line: bat "${toolbelt}/sf update". The error message was: bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
I managed to get rid of this error by adding the following code line: env.PATH = env.PATH + ";c:\\Windows\\System32".
This suggestion came from the following knowledge article:
knowledge article
I'm not sure if this correction was the right one, but it did make the error message bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. go away.
Once this error was resolved, the script ran into the next unknown command, which was in the same line of code, e.g. the command 'sf' in the line of code bat "${toolbelt}/sf update
One thing I tried was the following: Adding, right below the line env.PATH = env.PATH + ";c:\\Windows\\System32", the following code line: env.PATH = env.PATH + ";C:\Program Files\sf\bin". But that didn't work. I still got the same error message.
Can somebody shed her/his light on this issue?
